# is done method in Jamine just waits for few seconds or does it to something else as well

Tags: jasmine

I wrote this spec. I dispatches an event. I wait for the event to be received and handled. To wait, I simply use `done`. It made me wonder, does `done` just waits for certain seconds or does it also do something else?

```
fit('should show dialog box when uploading a file is aborted', (done) => {
    let newComponent = component;
    console.log("component is ",newComponent);

    let file1 = new File(["dd"], "file1",{type:'image/png'});

    spyOn(newComponent,'showDialog');

    let reader = newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);
    expect(reader).toBeTruthy();
    expect(reader.onabort).toBeTruthy();
    reader.abort();
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.showDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
    /*done is nothing but wait it seems. It makes the test case wait. This is required as the event
    fired (error) is async. So taht the test case doesn't fiinish before the event is handled, done/wait
    is added.
    */
    done();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

`done` is wait but not in the sense I thought. It is not a `timeout` which is always run. I think `done` acts as a checkpoint in `Jasmine`. When `Jasmine` sees that a spec uses `done`, it knows that it cannot proceed to the next step (say run next spec or mark this spec as finished) unless the code leg containing `done` has been run.

For example, jasmine passes this spec even though it should fail as it doesn't wait for setTimeout to be called.

```
fit('lets check done',()=>{
    let i=0;
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("in timeout");
      expect(i).toBeTruthy();//the spec should fail as i is 0
    },1000);
    //jasmine reaches this point and see there is no expectation so it passes the spec
  });
```

But if my intention is that Jasmine waits for the the async code in `setTimeout`, then I use `done` in the async code

```
fit('lets check done',(done)=>{
    let i=0;
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("in timeout");
      expect(i).toBeTruthy();//with done, the spec now correctly fails with reason Expected 0 to be truthy.
      done();//this should make jasmine wait for this code leg to be called before startinng the next spec or declaring the verdict of this spec
    },1000);
  });
```

Note that `done` should be called where I want to check the assertions.

```
fit('lets check done',(done)=>{
    let i=0;
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("in timeout");
      expect(i).toBeTruthy();//done not used at the right place, so spec will incorrectly ypass again!.
      //done should have been called here as I am asserting in this code leg.
    },1000);
    done();//using done here is not right as this code leg will be hit inn normal execution of it.
  });
```